# why adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); is not working?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to delete a row from listview and adapter, and also from database. Here is my WebMessageAdapter.java class in which I am calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but it does not refreshes the list. When i come back from other activity, the list is again populated with data just deleted. I don't understand what i am missing or where..?

Thanks.

```
package com.utility;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.activity.ContactInfoActivity;
import com.activity.MYApplication;
import com..activity.R;
import com.database.WebMessageCore;

public class WebMessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WebMessageCore> implements
        OnClickListener {

    Context _Context;
    ArrayList<WebMessageCore> _WebMsgList;
    WebMessageCore _WebMsgCore;
    TextView _MsgContent;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ImageView Arrow;
    ImageView imgDel;

    MYApplication application;
    WebMessageCore selectedWebMsgCore;

    public WebMessageAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            ArrayList<WebMessageCore> contactList) {

        super(context, resource, contactList);
        _Context = context;
        _WebMsgList = contactList;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return _WebMsgList.size();
    }

    public WebMessageCore getItem(int position) {
        return _WebMsgList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.txtmessage = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.meassage);
            holder.txtPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
            holder.txtdate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.datetime);
            holder.Arrow = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.settingArrow);
            holder.imgDelete = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dlet);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        _WebMsgCore = _WebMsgList.get(position);
        holder.txtName.setText(_WebMsgCore.getName());
        holder.txtmessage.setText(_WebMsgCore.getMessage());
        holder.txtPhone.setText(_WebMsgCore.getMobileNo());
        holder.txtdate.setText(_WebMsgCore.getRecDate());

        holder.imgDelete.setTag(_WebMsgCore);
        holder.imgDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
        holder.Arrow.setTag(_WebMsgCore);
        holder.Arrow.setOnClickListener(this);
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView Arrow;
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtmessage;
        TextView txtPhone;
        TextView txtdate;
        ImageView imgDelete;

    }

    public WebMessageCore getSelectedWebMsgCore() {
        return selectedWebMsgCore;
    }

    public void setSelectedWebMsgCore(WebMessageCore selectedWebMsgCore) {
        this.selectedWebMsgCore = selectedWebMsgCore;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.dlet:
            WebMessageCore tempWebMsgCore = (WebMessageCore) v.getTag();
            _WebMsgList.remove(tempWebMsgCore);   
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
        case R.id.settingArrow:
            callContactInfoActivity(v);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }



    private void callContactInfoActivity(View v) {
        WebMessageCore tempWebMsgCore = (WebMessageCore) v.getTag();
        WebMessageAdapter.this.setSelectedWebMsgCore(tempWebMsgCore);
        Intent newActivity = new Intent(_Context, ContactInfoActivity.class);
        newActivity.putExtra("id", tempWebMsgCore.getId());
        newActivity.putExtra("name", tempWebMsgCore.getName());
        newActivity.putExtra("message", tempWebMsgCore.getMessage());
        newActivity.putExtra("mobilenumber", tempWebMsgCore.getMobileNo());
        _Context.startActivity(newActivity);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try calling invalidateViews() on the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
WebMessageAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**EDIT:**

remove your `public void onClick(View v) {}`, and change to:

```
holder.imgDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        _WebMsgList.remove(position);   
        WebMessageAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried that too, but the row comes back when i switch between activities.

Comment: Tried and same results. Thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 0):

Dont add the model object of `_WebMsgCore` in the `holder.imgDelete.setTag(_WebMsgCore);` in `getView()` Method.  In place of that add `position` in the `holder.imgDelete.setTag(position)` and in `onClick()` callback method get the position from the Tag and remove the `item` from the `position` which you received and do call `notifyDataSetChanged()` of an adapter.

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Anieeh, can you elaborate on "...get the position from the Tag and remove the item from the position which you received..." as it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement seton onclick listener for the convertView,

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    _WebMsgList.remove(position);   
    WebMessageAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Okay i tried what u said, but it is not giving me even click effect on the row or imgDelete. Any other possiblities.. Thanks.